# Why does the setuid bit work inconsistently?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, privileges, setuid

I wrote the code:

```c
// a.c
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
  system("/bin/sh");
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with command:

```
gcc a.c -o a.out
```

added setuid bit on it:

```
sudo chown root.root a.out
sudo chmod 4755 a.out
```

On Ubuntu 14.04, when I run as general user, I got root privilege.

but on Ubuntu 16.04, I still got current user's shell.

Why is it different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What changed is that `/bin/sh` either became `bash` or stayed `dash` which got an additional flag `-p` mimicking bash's behaviour.

Bash requires the `-p` flag to not drop setuid privilege as explained in its [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html):

> If  the  shell  is  started  with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user
>   (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell  functions
>   are  not  inherited  from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE
>   variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored, **and the effective  user  id  is
>   set to the real user id**.  If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior
>   is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.

Before, `dash` didn't care about this and allowed setuid execution (by doing nothing to prevent it). But [Ubuntu 16.04's `dash`'s manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dash.1.html) has an additional option described, similar to `bash`:

> -p priv
>   Do not attempt to reset effective uid if it does not match uid. **This is not set by default to help avoid incorrect usage** by
>   setuid root programs via system(3) or popen(3).

This option didn't exist in [upstream](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/dash.1?h=v0.5.8) (which might not be have been reactive to a proposed patch<sup>[*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734869)</sup>) nor Debian 9 but is present in Debian buster which got the patch since 2018.

NOTE: as explained by Stéphane Chazelas, it's too late to invoke `"/bin/sh -p"` in `system()` because `system()` runs anything given through `/bin/sh` and so the setuid is already dropped. [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519343/251756)'s answer explains how to handle this, in the code before `system()`.

<sup>*</sup> more details on history [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1215660) and [there](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734869).

Comment: `system("bash -p")` runs `sh -c "bash -p"` so the privileges have already been dropped when `bash` is executed.

Comment: oh well ok. I'll remove the "solution" part better handled by derobert's answer anyway.

Comment: See also https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734869

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu fixed dash in wily (15.10). https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1215660

Comment: So to sumarize: Debian fixed this in buster (not current 9) and Ubuntu in 15.10 so between 14.04 and 16.04 . I'll add your informations.

Comment: Note that Debian used to go the other way round. It used to patch bash so as *not* to drop privileges. Whether it's an improvement is arguable. Now, people who want to do a `system()` with elevated privileges (which, granted, they shouldn't in the first place) end-up doing a `setresuid()` before which is a lot worse as then the shell doesn't know it's suid so doesn't activate the mode where it doesn't trust its environment.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the shell is changing its effective user ID back to the real user ID as part of its startup for some reason or another. You could verify this by adding:

```c
/* needs _GNU_SOURCE; non-Linux users see setregid/setreuid instead */
uid_t euid = geteuid(), egid = getegid();
setresgid(egid, egid, egid);
setresuid(euid, euid, euid);
```

before your `system()`. (Actually, even on Linux, you probably only need to set the real ones; the saved ones should be fine to leave alone. This is just brute force to debug. Depending on why you're set-id, you may of course need to save the real IDs somewhere as well.)

[Also, if this isn't just an exercise learning how setid works, then there are lot of security issues to worry about, especially when calling a shell. There are many environment variables, for example, that affect the shell's behavior. Prefer an already-existing approach like `sudo` if at all possible.]

Comment: I concentrated on the why it changed, while you provided the how to avoid the issue. +1

Comment: Of course, if you really do need somewhere to save the real IDs, the saved ID is an *awfully* convenient place to do it. Especially if the effective IDs are not root:root.